# Negative seek in write mode

Tags: python, amazon-s3, gzip, file-handling, oserror

I downloaded a zipped file from S3 and tried to unzip it:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/DataPump_10000838.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    testList = []
    for i in zip_ref.namelist():
        if (i.startswith("__MACOSX/") == False):
            val = '/tmp/'+i
            testList.append(val)
```

Now, there are a few unzipped files in my `/tmp` folder. I want to open those files, gzip and move to an S3 bucket. The paths to the unzipped files are present in the `testList`

```
s3_filename = 'sample'

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('testunzipping')    
    
    for i in testList:
        with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
            source_file = stack.enter_context(open(i , mode="rb"))
            destination_file = io.BytesIO()
            destination_file_gz = stack.enter_context(gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=destination_file, mode='wb'))
            while True:
                chunk = source_file.read(1024)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                destination_file_gz.write(chunk)
            destination_file_gz.seek(0)
            
            bucket.upload_fileobj(destination_file_gz, fileName)
```

I am trying this but I get an error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Negative seek in write mode",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 51, in <module>\n    destination_file_gz.seek(0)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/gzip.py\", line 384, in seek\n    raise OSError('Negative seek in write mode')\n"
  ]
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Python's gzip wrapper doesn't support seeking.  Though, that likely doesn't matter, since you want to upload the gzip'd bytes, not the decompressed bytes that would result from a seek on the gzip view.  Additionally, you need to `close` the gzip file, since it doesn't know that you're done with the writing, and may contain a final buffer to flush:

```
    # Ensure the gzip wrapper is done writing its data
    destination_file_gz.close()

    # Seek to the start of the raw data, not the gzip'd version
    destination_file.seek(0)
    # And upload that raw data    
    bucket.upload_fileobj(destination_file, fileName)
```

Comment: Then I would get an ```"I/O operation on closed file.",```error :(

Comment: @x89 Ahh, yep, you're not closing the gz file before using it, see my edit.

Comment: I see that the files are now created in S3. However, the file type is undetected (-). Also, when I download the file and open it, it's just weird characters. How do I know if it's successfully gzipped?

Comment: If you need to set the content type, then add `ContentType='application/gzip'` to your upload call.  You should be able to open the file with a gzip reader.  I'd test it out with whatever component you want to read these files.

Comment: Did you mean like this ```bucket.upload_fileobj(destination_file, fileName, ContentType='application/gzip')``` This throws ```bucket_upload_fileobj() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ContentType```

Comment: If you have a question about how to specify a content type, please open a question to that effect.